# How to show a style at the start of the Style Gallery in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a query wrt to getting the styles in word to show in the style gallery.

I have created a style (Table Heading Cond) that i use often, and i would like it to show in the first row of the styles gallery -- next to the heading styles. presently, it shows right at the bottom of the gallery.

[image]

Can you please provide me guidance on how i can accomplish this?

I have tried this via 'Manage Styles' but im not able to connect the dots.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so very close with the 'Manage Styles' screen:

From where you are on the screenshot.

1. Highlight the style
2. Click 'Show'
3. Click 'Assign Value...' and change it to 1.
4. Click OK to close the Window.
5. Once it appears in the Styles window (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S, or click the pop-out icon under the gallery if not showing), right-click it and select 'Add to Quick Style Gallery'.
6. You're done!

Comment: aah... that works.. Silas, thanks v much for the instructions.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this as the solution. 

In case someone else finds this, and needs a fuller explanation: http://shaunakelly.com/word/styles/quick-styles-gallery.html